# Building a reactjs app so it is hosted with a root URL parameter

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs app that I want to be hosted at:

```
https://localhost/testpp/
https://dev.mysite.com/testapp/
https://prod.mysite.com/testapp/
```

When I use `react-scripts build` to do the production build, the index.html that is generated in the build folder has links inserted like this:

```
<link href="/static/css/2.7118e3f5.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/main.efda1f21.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/static/js/2.a33cce7b.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.0d57a210.chunk.js"></script>
```

when the browser tries to download `/static/css/2.7118e3f5.chunk.css` it fails because it should be trying to get it from `testapp/static/css/2.7118e3f5.chunk.css`

I've then tried adding `"homepage": "/testapp"` to package.json, which now generates the correct links e.g.:

```
<script src="testapp/static/js/main.0d57a210.chunk.js"></script>
```

But now when I navigate to `https://dev.mysite.com/testapp/static/js/main.0d57a210.chunk.js` the response is always the index.html page, rather than the js file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths on mine i'm using `homepage: "withoutSlash"` and if using react router... add the `basename`

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve expected outcome by creating a route in `App.js` and redirect user to the `testapp` route.

In `App.js`

```
return (
  // ... your routes logic

  <Redirect from="/" to="testapp" />
)
```